# How to flip the raw camera image horizontally, when using official flutter camera plugin?

Tags: flutter, camera, flutter-web

I am currently developing a flutter webapp, where the user should be able to preview the camera and manually save a picture. Therefore I use the official camera plugin.
I am able to initialize the camera, preview the content and save a picture on button press.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

late List<CameraDescription> _cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  _cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(const CameraApp());
}

class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CameraApp> createState() => _CameraAppState();
}

class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
  late CameraController controller;
  Image? image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // define and initialize the camera controller once
    controller = CameraController(
      _cameras[0],
      ResolutionPreset.max,
      imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg,
    );
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    }).catchError((Object e) {
      if (e is CameraException) {
        switch (e.code) {
          case 'CameraAccessDenied':
            print('User denied camera access.');
            break;
          default:
            print('Handle other errors.');
            break;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            CameraPreview(controller), // shows preview
            if (image != null) image!,
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                // take picture
                try {
                  final XFile file = await controller.takePicture();
                  // load the picture as bytes
                  final blob = await file.readAsBytes();
                  // try to flip it horizontally
                  final img.Image? original = img.decodeImage(blob);
                  if (original != null) {
                    final img.Image oriented = img.flipHorizontal(original);
                    final orientedBlob =
                        Uint8List.fromList(img.encodeJpg(oriented));
                    setState(() {
                      // set the image to show the output
                      image = Image.memory(orientedBlob);
                    });
                  }
                } catch (e) {
                  print(e);
                }
              },
              child: const Text("Digitalisieren"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem I have, is that the camera content (images) are in the wrong direction.

[image: shows the preview and rotated stored image]

The picture shows the preview on top and the flipped stored image below that.

I can save a picture and rotate it afterwards. But I would like to flip the image directly when it comes from the stream. So the preview displays it correctly.

Is there a way to do that, without editing the plugin? Maybe there is a flip or mirror option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Thanks to justAsascha](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27650#issuecomment-591028017) I found a solution or workaround, which transforms (flips) the CameraPreview, so that it is in the same direction as the stored image.

Just wrap the CameraPreview widget with a transform and rotate the y-axis by pi. This solution needs dart:math import, for the math.pi.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

...

Transform(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    transform: Matrix4.rotationY(math.pi),
    child: CameraPreview(controller),
),

...
```

Maybe there is a better solution then transforming the preview and also transforming the stored image.